# How do we find the programmatic name of a view's column?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, xpages

For some of my requirements, I have a notes view,

> Its column name is different from programmatic column Name..

So I wanna to find the column's programmatic name from Xpage.,

I searched the NotesViewColumn class, I did not find it there.

I want to get the column's programmtic name using Javascript (Xpage)...

Comment: Sorry all Please review the question once again., I want to get the property using SSJS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using SSJS you will have for example :

```
var nvc:NotesViewColumn
nvc.getItemName() -> programmatic name of column
nvc.getTitle() -> title of column
```

Answer (score 3):

The ItemName property of a NotesViewColumn object will contain the programmatic name for the column:  http://blagoevgrad.court-bg.org/help/help85_designer.nsf/Main?OpenFrameSet

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that on on the last (Advanced) tab of the Column properties infobox in Designer.

It'll be there under 'Programmatic Use' for Name:

Comment: Sorry all Please review the question once again., I want to get the property using SSJS